# LaserJet Pro M12w

Tags: hplip, laserjet

I have just bought a new printer, a LaserJet Pro M12w. It's so new that it isn't supported by HPLIP. Is there another driver that I could use until a proper one arrives?

Comment: You can file a bug in http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/support.html There are other ways also. Luckily you printer support android. So install eprint by hp in your android mobile and go on

Answer (score 2):

Install it by selecting the HP Laserjet Pro CP1025nw driver which is part of the [hplip package.](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=hplip)

Untested by me, but here's the Source:

https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Printer-Software-and-Drivers/HP-Laser-Jet-Pro-M12w-ubuntu-driver/td-p/5963452

Comment: So you have to install the hplip package first, right? How do you choose that driver for the device?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Think I solved for now, until the specific driver arrives. I chose the HP Laserjet Pro P1102w, and it works fine, but cannot print on duplex mode.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Worked on both Ubuntu 16 and 18.

Comment: Can you configure wireless printing in Linux?

Answer (score 1):

You could download the driver [here](http://foo2zjs.rkkda.com/). It's developed by community but works wonder.

Comment: I tried it on live ubuntu 18.04, but I could not make it work.

Comment: The link says "Forbidden"

Answer (score 0):

I installed the printer as wireless printer in Windows. Then I added the printer in Xubuntu's Printers dialog as network printer. The IP of the printer appeared there. Then I chose the IPP way and the device did not need specific driver.